# How to keep only the noun words in a wordlist? python NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, text-processing, wordnet, pos-tagger

I have a wordlist, which consists many subjects. The subjects were auto extracted from sentences. I would like to keep only the noun from the subjects. As u can see some of the subjects have adj which i want to delete it.

```
wordlist=['country','all','middle','various drinks','few people','its reputation','German Embassy','many elections']
returnlist=[]
for word in wordlist:
    x=wn.synsets(word)
    for syn in x:
        if syn.pos() == 'n':
            returnlist.append(word)
            break
print returnlist
```

the results of above is :

```
['country','it',  'middle']
```

However, I want to get the result should be look like this

```
   wordlist=['country','it', 'middle','drinks','people','reputation','German Embassy','elections']
```

How to do that?

Comment: you want to use nltk only

Comment: not really. as long as i can get the idea result. any method is acceptable

Comment: `middel` not noun as well as `it`(pronoun)

Comment: "German Embassy" is a noun phrase, not a noun.  If that's what you want, look for NP extraction tools.

Comment: @HishamKaram "The middle" is a noun, although the predominant meaning is of course adjectival.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your list is a result of not well tokenized text so i tokenized them again
then search `pos` of all words to find nouns which pos contains NN :

```
>>> text=' '.join(wordlist).lower()
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
>>> tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
>>> nouns = [word for word,pos in tags if (pos == 'NN' or pos == 'NNP' or pos == 'NNS' or pos == 'NNPS')
]
>>> nouns
['country', 'drinks', 'people', 'Embassy', 'elections']
```

Comment: you return adjectives

Answer (score 0):

```
adjectives = ['many', 'any', 'few', 'some', 'various'] # ...
wordlist = ['country','all','middle','various drinks','few people','its reputation','German Embassy','many elections']
returnlist = []
for word in wordlist:
    for adj in adjectives:
        word = word.lower().replace(adj, '').strip()
    returnlist.append(word)
print(returnlist)
```

Comment: you return adjectives  and pronoun `['country', 'all', 'middle', 'drinks', 'people', 'its reputation', 'german embassy', 'elections']`